# XSL Transform with three source documents to create report

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having difficulty creating an xsl transformation. My three source documents are similar to:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
 <Workgroup>
  <Items>
   <Item WorkgroupID="4001" WorkgroupCenter="Center1"/>
   <Item WorkgroupID="4002" WorkgroupCenter="Center1"/>
   <Item WorkgroupID="4003" WorkgroupCenter="Center2"/>
  </Items>
 </Workgroup>
 <Staff>
  <Items>
   <Item StaffName="Anne Jones" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="AJ1" />
   <Item StaffName="Bill Smith" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="BS1" />
   <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1" />
   <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1" />
   <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1" />
   <Item StaffName="Frank Miller" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="FM1" />
  </Items>
 </Staff>
 <Membership>
  <Items>
   <Item StaffID="AJ1" WorkgroupID="4001" />
   <Item StaffID="AJ1" WorkgroupID="4001" />
   <Item StaffID="AJ1" WorkgroupID="4003" />
   <Item StaffID="CG1" WorkgroupID="4001" />
   <Item StaffID="CG1" WorkgroupID="4003" />
   <Item StaffID="DH1" WorkgroupID="4002" />
   <Item StaffID="ED1" WorkgroupID="4003" />
  </Items>
 </Membership>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

My desired output is

```
Center   | Unique Staff | Count (Workgroups)
------------------------------
Center1  |    1         |   2
Center2  |    2         |   1
Center3  |    1         |   0
```

The third column is simply a count of items in the Workgroup document by the "WorkgroupCenter" attribute - this is not giving me any trouble.

The first column is obviously the Center.

The second column is the count of unique members of each Center (indicated by attribute "StaffCenter" in the "Staff" Items) excluding any Staff Items that do not have a corresponding entry in the "Membership" Items (StaffID). This means that for this column, the WorkgroupCenter attribute is ignored.

I am limited to XSLT 1.0.

Edited to add what I have attempted so far. I'm stuck at trying to aggregate the counts as noted by my comment in the code. I should note the environment is a SharePoint 2010 Data Form Web Part. My example was simplified, so I've edited my existing code to match:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
 <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
 <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
 <xsl:param name="dvt_firstrow">1</xsl:param>
 <xsl:param name="dvt_nextpagedata" />
 <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:key name="staffCenter" match="/dsQueryResponse/Staff/Items/Item" use="@StaffCenter"/>
 <xsl:key name="workgroupCenter" match="/dsQueryResponse/Workgroup/Items/Item" use="@WorkgroupCenter"/>

 <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
  <xsl:variable name="centers" select="/dsQueryResponse/Staff/Items/Item[count (. | key('staffCenter',@StaffCenter)[1]) = 1]" />
  <xsl:variable name="workgroupCenters" select="/dsQueryResponse/Workgroup/Items/Item[count (. | key('workgroupCenter',@WorkgroupCenter)[1]) = 1]" />

  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Center</th>
    <th>Unique Representative for Activities</th>
    <th>Active Workgroups</th>
   </tr>

   <xsl:for-each select="$centers">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@StaffCenter" />
     </td>
     <td>
      <xsl:variable name="CurrentCenterNodes" select="key('staffCenter',@StaffCenter)" />

      <!-- This gives me count of the number of instances of a particular staff member. 
           What I want is a count of the number of staff members where their total is greater than 0 -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$CurrentCenterNodes">
       <xsl:value-of select="@StaffID"/> -
       <xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Membership/Items/Item[@Title=current()/@StaffID])"/>
       <br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </td>
     <td>
      <xsl:variable name="WorkgroupCenterLeadNodes" select="key('workgroupCenter',@StaffCenter)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="count($WorkgroupCenterLeadNodes)" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Additionally, the Membership document is necessary because if a Staff Member does not exist in it then they should not be counted.

Comment: Could you post what you have so far, so that we can fix it - instead of having to write your code for you from scratch?

Comment: Is the Membership document actually needed to produce this output? If it is, then I have misunderstood the relationship of the input and the output. And: have you studied Muenchian grouping? Because if you need to tackle grouping problems in XSLT 1.0, you will need to.

Comment: @michael.hor257k My code is added. Sorry for the delay, had to edit it to match my simplified example.

Comment: @MichaelKay I did start with the muenchian approach, but I feel I'm missing something simple here. The Membership document is necessary because if a staff member does not have a record in there then they should not be counted.

Comment: I am somewhat confused here, because I see no reference to other documents in your XSLT. You say you have "three source documents" but you show only one - and that one is not well-formed XML (no single root element).

Comment: I also don't understand your output. Center2 has 1 workgroup (4003). There are 3 distinct staff members assigned to this workgroup (AJ1, CG1, ED1). Out of these three, only CJ1 belongs to Center2. Yet you show 2.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I updated my xml and xsl to reflect the issue with the documents. My expected output is correct because the Unique Staff column considers the StaffCenter attribute in the Staff/Items/Item nodes, not the WorkgroupCenter attribute of the Workgroup/Items/Item nodes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I considered the same attribute and got the result I stated. I will post an interim answer shortly so we can sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of moving this forward, consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="staff-by-center" match="Staff/Items/Item" use="@StaffCenter"/>
<xsl:key name="workgroup-by-center" match="Workgroup/Items/Item" use="@WorkgroupCenter"/>
<xsl:key name="membership-by-workgroup" match="Membership/Items/Item" use="@WorkgroupID"/>
<xsl:key name="staff-by-id" match="Staff/Items/Item" use="@StaffID"/>

<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse">
    <root>
        <!-- for each distinct center -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Staff/Items/Item[count(.|key('staff-by-center', @StaffCenter)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="center" select="@StaffCenter" />
            <!-- workgroups associated with the current center -->
            <xsl:variable name="workgroups" select="key('workgroup-by-center', $center)" />
            <!-- memberships associated with the workgroups -->
            <xsl:variable name="memberships" select="key('membership-by-workgroup', $workgroups/@WorkgroupID)" />
            <!-- distinct staff listed in memberships -->
            <xsl:variable name="staff" select="key('staff-by-id', $memberships/@StaffID)" />
            <center>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$center" />
                </name>
                <workgroups>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$workgroups" />
                </workgroups>
                <memberships>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$memberships" />
                </memberships>
                <all-staff>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$staff" />
                </all-staff>
                <center-staff>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$staff[@StaffCenter=$center]" />
                </center-staff>
            </center>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used an XML result and **copied** the relevant nodes instead of just **counting** them, so that we can see exactly what each step does. Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <center>
    <name>Center1</name>
    <workgroups>
      <Item WorkgroupID="4001" WorkgroupCenter="Center1"/>
      <Item WorkgroupID="4002" WorkgroupCenter="Center1"/>
    </workgroups>
    <memberships>
      <Item StaffID="AJ1" WorkgroupID="4001"/>
      <Item StaffID="AJ1" WorkgroupID="4001"/>
      <Item StaffID="CG1" WorkgroupID="4001"/>
      <Item StaffID="DH1" WorkgroupID="4002"/>
    </memberships>
    <all-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Anne Jones" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="AJ1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1"/>
    </all-staff>
    <center-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Anne Jones" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="AJ1"/>
    </center-staff>
  </center>
  <center>
    <name>Center2</name>
    <workgroups>
      <Item WorkgroupID="4003" WorkgroupCenter="Center2"/>
    </workgroups>
    <memberships>
      <Item StaffID="AJ1" WorkgroupID="4003"/>
      <Item StaffID="CG1" WorkgroupID="4003"/>
      <Item StaffID="ED1" WorkgroupID="4003"/>
    </memberships>
    <all-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Anne Jones" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="AJ1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1"/>
    </all-staff>
    <center-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
    </center-staff>
  </center>
  <center>
    <name>Center3</name>
    <workgroups/>
    <memberships/>
    <all-staff/>
    <center-staff/>
  </center>
</root>
```

Now, as you can see, these results do not match your expected output - for example, no group of nodes under Center2 has a count of 2. So either I am grouping the wrong nodes, or your expected counts are off. If the former, please edit your question and elaborate on the logic that needs to be applied (how would one arrive at the expected result manually).

---

### Added:

> The second column is the count of unique members of each Center
>   (indicated by attribute "StaffCenter" in the "Staff" Items) excluding
>   any Staff Items that do not have a corresponding entry in the
>   "Membership" Items (StaffID).

Okay then this should be relatively easy:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="staff-by-center" match="Staff/Items/Item" use="@StaffCenter"/>
<xsl:key name="memberhip-by-staff" match="Membership/Items/Item" use="@StaffID"/>

<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse">
    <root>
        <!-- for each distinct center -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Staff/Items/Item[count(.|key('staff-by-center', @StaffCenter)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="center" select="@StaffCenter" />
            <!-- staff at current center -->
            <xsl:variable name="all-staff" select="key('staff-by-center', $center)" />
            <!-- exclude staff with no memberships -->
            <xsl:variable name="staff" select="$all-staff[key('memberhip-by-staff', @StaffID)]" />
            <center>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$center" />
                </name>
                <all-staff>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$all-staff" />
                </all-staff>
                <staff>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$staff" />
                </staff>
            </center>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <center>
    <name>Center1</name>
    <all-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Anne Jones" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="AJ1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Bill Smith" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="BS1"/>
    </all-staff>
    <staff>
      <Item StaffName="Anne Jones" StaffCenter="Center1" StaffID="AJ1"/>
    </staff>
  </center>
  <center>
    <name>Center2</name>
    <all-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1"/>
    </all-staff>
    <staff>
      <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1"/>
    </staff>
  </center>
  <center>
    <name>Center3</name>
    <all-staff>
      <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1"/>
      <Item StaffName="Frank Miller" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="FM1"/>
    </all-staff>
    <staff>
      <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1"/>
    </staff>
  </center>
</root>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help Michael. I've clarified the desired output of the 2nd (of 3) columns in the question. Here is my clarification as well: **The second column is the count of unique members of each Center (indicated by attribute "StaffCenter" in the "Staff" Items) excluding any Staff Items that do not have a corresponding entry in the "Membership" Items (StaffID). This means that for this column, the WorkgroupCenter attribute is ignored.** So, Staff Member "ED1" should show up under Center3 b/c of the value of StaffCenter, and for this column, should ignore WorkgroupCenter.

Comment: @Chloraphil See if the added XSLT manages to select the correct group.