# Why does using a variable change the output in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to understand how an answer to a previous question of mine works. Here is the old question: [XSL Transform with three source documents to create report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657932/xsl-transform-with-three-source-documents-to-create-report)

I have two questions.
One, why does the use of a variable cause the output to change between the nodes "staff-with-membership" and "staff-with-membership-using-variable" (under Center3). My expectation would be that using a variable would have no effect.

Second, how does the "filtering" work for the variable "staff" - I would expect the code "key('membership-by-staff', @StaffID)" to return either one node or none, but somehow it manages to seemingly return two for "Center2" (Charles Glover and Donald Hill).

Source xml:

```
<root>
 <Staff>
  <Items>
   <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1" />
   <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1" />
   <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1" />
   <Item StaffName="Frank Miller" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="FM1" />   
  </Items>
 </Staff>
 <Membership>
  <Items>
   <Item MembershipStaff_ID="CG1" />
   <Item MembershipStaff_ID="DH1" />
   <Item MembershipStaff_ID="ED1" />   
  </Items>
 </Membership>
</root>
```

Xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="staff-by-center" match="Staff/Items/Item" use="@StaffCenter"/>
<xsl:key name="membership-by-staff" match="Membership/Items/Item" use="@MembershipStaff_ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <!-- for each distinct center -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Staff/Items/Item[count(.|key('staff-by-center', @StaffCenter)[1]) = 1]">

            <xsl:variable name="center" select="@StaffCenter" />

            <!-- staff at current center -->
            <xsl:variable name="all-staff" select="key('staff-by-center', $center)" />

            <!-- exclude staff with no memberships -->
            <xsl:variable name="staff" select="$all-staff[key('membership-by-staff', @StaffID)]" />

            <!-- staff using variable for StaffID instead of attribute -->
            <xsl:variable name="myStaffId" select="@StaffID" />
            <xsl:variable name="staff-using-variable" select="$all-staff[key('membership-by-staff', $myStaffId)]" />

            <center>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$center" />
                </name>
                <all-staff-in-center>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$all-staff" />
                </all-staff-in-center>
                <staff-with-membership>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$staff" />
                </staff-with-membership>
                <membership>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('membership-by-staff',  @StaffID)" />
                </membership>
                <staff-with-membership-using-variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$staff-using-variable" />
                </staff-with-membership-using-variable>
            </center>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output xml:

```
<root>
   <center>
      <name>Center2</name>
      <all-staff-in-center>
         <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
         <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1"/>
      </all-staff-in-center>
      <staff-with-membership>
         <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
         <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1"/>
      </staff-with-membership>
      <membership>
         <Item MembershipStaff_ID="CG1"/>
      </membership>
      <staff-with-membership-using-variable>
         <Item StaffName="Charles Glover" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="CG1"/>
         <Item StaffName="Donald Hill" StaffCenter="Center2" StaffID="DH1"/>
      </staff-with-membership-using-variable>
   </center>
   <center>
      <name>Center3</name>
      <all-staff-in-center>
         <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1"/>
         <Item StaffName="Frank Miller" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="FM1"/>
      </all-staff-in-center>
      <staff-with-membership>
         <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1"/>
      </staff-with-membership>
      <membership>
         <Item MembershipStaff_ID="ED1"/>
      </membership>
      <staff-with-membership-using-variable>
         <Item StaffName="Evan Dolan" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="ED1"/>
         <Item StaffName="Frank Miller" StaffCenter="Center3" StaffID="FM1"/>
      </staff-with-membership-using-variable>
   </center>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
        <xsl:variable name="myStaffId" select="@StaffID" />
        <xsl:variable name="staff-using-variable" select="$all-staff[key('membership-by-staff', $myStaffId)]" />
```

you select the `@StaffID` attribute for the context node (of the outer `for-each`) only.

In the expression `<xsl:variable name="staff" select="$all-staff[key('membership-by-staff', @StaffID)]" />` the attribute `@StaffID` is selected for each node in `$all-staff` as the expression is inside the predicate in square brackets. You would need to use `$all-staff[key('membership-by-staff', current()/@StaffID)]` to have the same result as with your use of the variable where you only select the `StaffID` of the context node.

As for `$all-staff` being filtered by the predicate `[key('membership-by-staff', @StaffID)]`, the predicate expression is evaluated for each node in `$all-staff` and tests whether there is a reference in `Membership/Items/Item`. There is for both the persons of `Center2` but only for one of `Center3`.

Comment: Martin, thank you for your explanation! I understand that now. Do you have any thoughts on my second question? Specifically, the result of "key('membership-by-staff', @StaffID)" returns a node-set of items from Membership/Items/Item, but is then used to filter the node-set represented by $all-staff, which is from Staff/Items/Item. I don't understand how that works.

Comment: @Chloraphil, I have tried to address your second question.

Comment: I got it, thanks! The key is realizing the "context" of the attribute inside a predicate - which you explained in your original answer, but took me several readings to grasp. Thank you for your patience.